# Can we store the output of a python program using objects and classes like, student details in excel sheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I want to store the data of students in an excel sheet using the programming using objects and classes. In classes using python we can get output of a student details using the parameters of the classes. We can create no of objects for no of students . I want all the data in an excel sheet in a format like each student details in a separate row and details in different columns.

Comment: you can save it as json format or use pickle to save class object

Comment: More convenient than JSON would be a csv of lists and dictionaries, no?